# Error in adding phone number to contacts_service

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a contact to the phone from a json data in flutter.

I have used contacts_service package. But I when I am trying to add the phone number to the model,"a String cant be assigned to a iterable error pops".

Could someone show the correct method of using this package and adding a contact.

My code is

```
onSaved: (val) =>
setState(() => _user.phones = val)),
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts), phones is an `Iterable` of `Item`, not an unique `String` :

```dart
// Phone numbers
Iterable<Item> phones = [];
```

where `Item` is a basic `key`/`value` object.

You need to format your `val` this way :

```dart
onSaved: (val) =>
    setState((){
        _user.phones = []..add(Item.fromMap({'label': 'work', 'value': val})); // Set the label of your choice
    });
),
```

Comment: tried using your code. It threw the error Item isnt a fucntion,and also something is wrong with the format as there is an error at the semi colon saying it is expecing a ')'

Comment: That throws throw no error, but

    newContact.displayName="Jerin";
    newContact.phones = []..add(Item.fromMap({'label': 'work', 'value': phoneNumber})); // Set the label of your choice
    // Add a contact
    // The contact must have a firstName / lastName to be successfully added
    await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);

This is what I tried,it executes but contact is not getting added. Is it because I havent given first name and last name ? but the model doesnt have a firstname and a last name ?

Comment: I tried assigning every name possible 

newContact.displayName="Jerin";
    newContact.familyName="Cherian";
    newContact.givenName="Cherian";
    newContact.middleName="Cherian";
    newContact.phones = []..add(Item.fromMap({'label': 'work', 'value': phoneNumber})); // Set the label of your choice
    // Add a contact